# Get transaction history of a particular nft token

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js, ethers.js

I want to retrieve all the transactions (for getting ownership history) of a given NFT(erc721) tokenId. How is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this by filtering all the "transfer" events using `getPastEvents` [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-contract.html#getpastevents). The `to`, `from` and `tokenId` are indexed on chain. So we can apply those filters.
Had to somehow take care of the infura limits by recursively calling the function.

Comment: Can you give your code link?